# Javascript: Como crear función que valide nombre de usuario > Debe empezar en mayúscula

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola como están? Debo realizar una función que valide el nombre de usuario:

- Pasa si al digitar el nombre, éste empieza por la primera letra en mayúscula y No inicia con espacios (true)
- De lo contrario (false)

El nombre se captura por un formulario de HTML a través de la variable "nombre_usuario"

Hago unas aclaraciones adicionales. La función debe llamarse tal cual así (con string como parámetro) porque el ejercicio me lo califica un bot

```
function validar_nombre_usuario(string)
```

Asi mismo, en HTML ya declaré la variable en un formulario, con nombre "nombre_usuario", entonces entiendo que primero debo obtenerla en Javascript con esta función

```
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_usuario");
```

Sin embargo, no he podido programar el método que me encuentre la primera letra, y hacer que la compare con una letra Mayúscula para validar si es TRUE o FALSE

El código completo en javascript que he planteado y que no me ha funcionado es el siguiente:

```
var nombre;
var texto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function validar_nombre_usuario(string){

 nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_usuario").value;

 if (nombre == texto.charAt(0)){
   return true;
 }
 else{
   return false;
 }
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar a usar una expresión regular, que en tu caso es sencilla porque solo tienes la condición de que el primer caracter sea una mayúscula.

Puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```js
let ejemplos = ["roberto","Andrea","Pepito", "Pablo\"\"","   Nope","Yes"]

function validar_nombre_usuario( nombre ) {
    return /^[A-Z].*/g.test( nombre );
}

ejemplos.forEach( n => {
  console.log( `¿Es válido '${n}'? ${validar_nombre_usuario(n) ? "Si" : "No" }` )
})
```

Para explicar un poco por encima la expresión regular `^[A-Z].*`:
`^` - Significa que la cadena comienza con ...
`[A-Z]` - Caracteres entre la `A` y la `Z`
`.*` - Cualquier caracter excepto saltos de línea (repetidos indefinidas veces)

Answer (score 1):

Una solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
if(nombre.charAt[0] === nombre.charAt[0].toUpperCase){
    return true;
```

Comment: Comparas que la primera letra del nombre sea igual a la primera letra del nombre pero en mayusculas.

Comment: Buena solución. Si devuelves directamente el resultado de la comparación, te ahorras el if.

Comment: Exacto, gracias.

Comment: Se quedaría así: return(nombre.charAt[0] === nombre.charAt[0].toUpperCase);

Comment: Gracias por responder, sin embargo, te doy un consejo para que enriquezcas tu respuesta: *añade una explicación, aunque sea breve de lo que hace tu código*, además si necesitas añadir detalles como el comentario que pusiste, es mejor que lo hagas en la respuesta, para ello haz clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: El problema de tu solución es que acepta nombres que empiezan con espacios. Y en lugar de `chartAt[0]` debería ser `.charAt(0)`, y en lugar de `toUpperCase` debería ser `toUpperCase()`

Comment: Toda la razón, la próxima vez lo puliré más. Gracias!